# movement of camera in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so me and my friends are making a camera select in unity and we wanted to add a cam "follow" so we have and followed a youtube tutorial editing it here and there to fit our purposes. But we have a problem when we run it the camera doesnt move to the car it just stay where we put. can anyone help please. Coded in c#

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camswitch : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject cam1;
    public GameObject cam2;
    public GameObject cam3;
    public GameObject follow;
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
    transform.position = target.position;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("1key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(true);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("2key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(true);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("3key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(true);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("4key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(true);
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue here seems to be that you never actually tell the camera to follow any of your other GameObjects. You tell the camera to always go to `target.position` which is set to whatever Vector3 coordinates you have placed in the inspector.

What I have done to the script is edited the target position and set it to the position of one of your cameras. You can change it accordingly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camswitch : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject cam1;
    public GameObject cam2;
    public GameObject cam3;
    public GameObject follow;
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
      target.transform.position = cam1.transform.position; //Change this to whatever camera you want it to follow.
      transform.position = target.position;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("1key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(true);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("2key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(true);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("3key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(true);
            follow.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("4key"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
            follow.SetActive(true);
            
            
        }
    }
}
```